# How can I figure out which registers are passed as parameters to a function in assembly?

Tags: assembly, calling-convention

As I know functions take parameters usually like this

```
push param1  
push param2  
push param3  
call func
```

But I've came across something like this recently

```
mov rdi,param1  
mov rsi,param2  
mov rax,param3  
call func
```

The second one is confusing because I don't know how many parameters the func will take so I can't comb out a natural mov instruction from a parameter conduction. Also god forbid, what will I do if both methods are used to pass parameters?

Is there an easy way to figure out which convention is used?

Comment: It is the ABI that define the calling convention. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) is the one for Windows and this [one](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi-0.99.7.pdf) is for System V (Like Linux).

Comment: Note that `RAX` isn't holding a parameter in any of the usual conventions, but under SysV `AL` holds the number of vector registers used. Also, private functions may use whatever argument passing they want (and optimizing compilers do make use of this).

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Comment: calling conventions can be different per target (arm, mips, x86) and per compiler and per version of the compiler.   So if you need to know this (hand writing assembly routines to link with C) then you should check the calling convention for that compiler, version, and target.  in some cases just a test function compiled and disassembled will do